# How to use ids from one dataframe to sum rows in another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I feel like this answer has been asked before, but I can't seem to find an answer to this question. Maybe my title is too vague, so feel free to change it.

So I have one data frame, a,  with ids the correspond to column name in data frame b. Both data frames are simplified versions of a much larger data frame.

here is data frame a

```
a <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("GEN[D00105].GT", 
"GEN[D00151].GT", "GEN[D00188].GT", "GEN[D86396].GT", "GEN[D86397].GT"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

here is data frame b

```
b <- structure(list(`GEN[D01104].GT` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0), `GEN[D01312].GT` = c(1, 0, 
2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0), `GEN[D01878].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0), `GEN[D01882].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), `GEN[D01952].GT` = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0), `GEN[D01953].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0), `GEN[D02053].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `GEN[D00316].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0), `GEN[D01827].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0), `GEN[D01881].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0), `GEN[D02044].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), `GEN[D02085].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0), `GEN[D02204].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0), `GEN[D02276].GT` = c(0, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), `GEN[D02297].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0), `GEN[D02335].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0), `GEN[D02397].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `GEN[D00856].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), `GEN[D00426].GT` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `GEN[D02139].GT` = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0), `GEN[D02168].GT` = c(0, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to be able to use the ids from data frame a to sum the row in data frame b that have a matching id if that makes sense.

So in the past, I just did something like

```
b$affected.samples <- (b$`GEN[D86396].GT` + b$`GEN[D86397].GT` + b$`GEN[D00105].GT` + b$`GEN[D00151].GT` + b$`GEN[D00188].GT`)
```

which got annoying and took to much time, so I moved over to

```
b$affected.samples <- rowSums(b[,c(1:5)])
```

Which isn't too bad for this example but with my large data set, my sample can be all over the place, and it's starting to take too much time to finds where everything is. I was hoping there is a way just to use my data frame a to sum the correct rows in data frame b.

Hopefully, I gave this is all the information you need! Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the 'V1' column as a `character` string, use that to select the columns of 'b' (assuming these column names are found in 'b') and get the `rowSums`

```
rowSums( b[as.character(a$V1)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: BINGO!!!!! That is perfect!! short and simple!! Just the way we all like it!! Thanks so much for the help. I really appreciate it! This is going to save me so much time!!!!!!!